# Нажатие на элемент recyclerView

Tags: java, android, espresso

Пишу тест, в котором хочу обработать нажатие на элемент списка recyclerView.

Если к элементу он обращается и никаких ошибок не происходит:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.card_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(3));
```

То при попытке проверить что в такой то позиции находится такое число:

```
onView(withText(SCORE)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "148"

При попытке же нажать на саму позицию:

```
onView(withId(R.id.card_recycler_view))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Выдаёт следующее:

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction@4246947' on view 'with id: com.fentury.testapp:id/card_recycler_view'.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим recycler'ом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы предложил следующий вариант, реализовать метод в классе:

```
fun checkTextOnPosition(position: Int, text: String) {
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recyclerView).atPosition(position))
        .check(ViewAssertions.matches(hasDescendant(withText(text))))
```

}

Где будете просто в зависимости от нужных вам параметров вызывать данный метод, задавая позицию и текст которую хотите проверить.
Дополнительно придётся реализовать метод:

```
fun withRecyclerView(recyclerViewId: Int): RecyclerViewMatcher {
return RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId)
}
```

А вместе с ним и класс:

```
class RecyclerViewMatcher(private val recyclerViewId: Int) {

fun atPosition(position: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return atPositionOnView(position, -1)
}

fun atPositionOnView(position: Int, targetViewId: Int): Matcher<View> {

    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        internal var resources: Resources? = null
        internal var childView: View? = null

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            var idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId)
            if (this.resources != null) {
                try {
                    idDescription = this.resources!!.getResourceName(recyclerViewId)
                } catch (var4: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                    idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)", recyclerViewId)
                }

            }

            description.appendText("RecyclerView with id: $idDescription at position: $position")
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {

            this.resources = view.resources

            if (childView == null) {
                val recyclerView = view.rootView.findViewById(recyclerViewId) as RecyclerView
                if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView.id == recyclerViewId) {
                    val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)
                    if (viewHolder != null) {
                        childView = viewHolder.itemView
                    }
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }

            if (targetViewId == -1) {
                return view === childView
            } else {
                val targetView = childView!!.findViewById(targetViewId)
                return view === targetView
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Также дополнительно если нужно прокликивать по элементам:

```
fun clickOnTextInPosition(position: Int, title: String) {
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView))
        .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<CurrencySelectorItemHolder>(position, ViewActions.click()))
}
```